# Getting a json file when I am exporting dashboard from apache supertset. Unable to import that

Tags: dashboard, apache-superset

I have a dashboard built on Apache Superset. When I am exporting it I am getting a JSON file whereas after watching tutorials I believe a folder should be exported.
I tried to import that JSON but it throws an error, can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable  VERSIONED_EXPORT future flag under config.py to  be able to export the dashboard as a ZIP file.